# How to use Switchee

Tags: conditionals, plugin, switchee

I am unable to get Switchee to work. I have installed the Switchee 2.0.6 with ExpressionEngine 2.5.2.

Here is the conditional statement that I'd like to use, where "champions" is a custom field:

```
{if champions == "team 3"}
   <p>team 3</p>
{/if}
```

and here is how I've incorporated Switchee:

```
{exp:switchee variable = "{champions}" parse="inward"}
    {case value == "team 3"}
        <p>team 3</p>
    {/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```

My switchee statement shows nothing in my template in my browser. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation a bit more carefully, you'll see that the `{case value="xxx"}` tags only use a single `=` sign.

So, this should work

```
{exp:switchee variable = "{champions}" parse="inward"}
    {case value="team 3"}
        <p>team 3</p>
    {/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```

Comment: oh wow (feeling silly). thanks for seeing that error! working now

Comment: It happens to all of us. Glad it was an easy one!